# python: problem with Sqlalchemy and Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyinstaller

I wrote a code with pyqt5 pandas sqlalchemy pyodbc libraries
but when I want to make an exe from my py file with pyinstaller I get this error:

```
in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 632, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 529, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1029, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 854, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 274, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-sqlalchemy.py", line 32, in <module>
    dialects = eval(dialects.strip())
  File "<string>", line 0

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I searched for about 2 hours bet I couldn't find any solution

if you need to see my code comment on it and I will update the question with my code that I want to make exe of

Comment: It seems that the [``dialects.strip()``](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/98aa4508455f3baaa8f15754ae5c95ee0e32806e/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-sqlalchemy.py#L31-L32) returns no results.

Comment: yes i installed it
when i try pip install sqlalcheny i get:
Requirement already satisfied: SqlALchemy in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.4.23)

Comment: sorry for the stupid question

Comment: no dude thats ok :D
do you ever had this problem?

Comment: is there any libraries like sqlalchemy to work with pandas?

Comment: If you do not need sqlalchemy (and I have understood that you need it, but I did not and ran across your post), one can simple exclude this in the command line of pyinstaller: `pyinstaller test.py --exclude-module sqlalchemy`

Answer (score 2):

I finally get it to work

I was exploring about my error till I found this:
[this](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6437)

and there was a guy that said:
if you install asyncio externally and you use above 3.3 python version then uninstall asyncio using pip uninstall asyncio it's works for me because 3.4 and above version added this in python-core so no need to add externally asyncio

and what I have done actually: pip uninstall asyncio
and it works like a charm!!!!

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when generating an executable with pyinstaller, simply run this line before invoking pyinstaller.

```
pip uninstall asyncio
```